# A plane,sphere and line all in an inequality

Tags: inequality, analytic-geometry

$x+y+z=4$

$x^2 +y^2+z^2=6$

If  $x$,$y$ and $z$ are real numbers that satisfy the equation above, and that they lie in the range of $[a,b]$,then find values of both a and b.

My attempt:-

Instead of using Lagrange Multipliers ,I tried to approach this problem using Geometric interpretation.

The solution set, being the intersection of a sphere and a plane, is a non-horizontal circle with a unique highest as well as lowest point. Since the solution set is symmetric in $x$ and $y$(WLOG),we must have $x=y$,at the point of maxima or minima.

Now,this question boils down to 2 variables and 2 equations.

$2x+z=4$

$2x^2 + z^2=6$

Solving these by plugging in $z=4-2x$ in the third equation,we get the value of $z=2$ or $2/3.$ 
So $a=2/3$ and $b=2$,but the answer is marked incorrect.

Question:-What is wrong with the above solution?

Comment: The argument that the system is symmetric, so maxima is when $x=y$ is specious.

Comment: @Macavity Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your use of symmetry disturbed me considerably when I first read your answer, along the lines of @Macavity ’s comment. But by treating $z$ specially, as you did (and as I did when I solved the problem), you still have the $x\leftrightarrow y$ symmetry, since the full symm. group is $\mathcal S_3$. So I believe that your argument is correct. In any event, when y ou make the substitution $z=4-x-y$, the other equation certainly exhibits $(x,y)$-symmetry, giving *ā posteriori* justification for your claim.

Comment: @Lubin How can improve this answer?(ie. how can I make it more rigorous?)

Comment: In general, just because a system is symmetric, solutions need not be symmetric - it just means the solution set is symmetric. i.e. If $(p,q)$ is a solution so is $(q,p)$, but $p=q$ is not necessary. You may want to read http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/do-symmetric-problems-have-symmetric-solutions for more.

Comment: I guess I have to retreat a bit and recognize @Macavity ’s objection. I’ll modify my answer to show my solution.

Comment: The result is fine, as Lubin and others point out. However there is an issue with your approach using symmetry - though it is a very common error, particularly as the exceptions to symmetry are rather rare. I have often used symmetry to guess at the answer, but the proof has to be more rigorous.

Comment: @Macavity Thanks for the pointing out the flaw.

Comment: A very simple example where the extremal points are not the symmetric ones is the butterfly curve $y^2=4x^2(1-x^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a different method, and found that one kind of extremal point has two coordinates equal to $1$ and the other equal to $2$; the other kind of extremal point has two coordinates equal to $5/3$, the other equal to $2/3$. That is, I found complete agreement with your results.

**EDIT**: In response to your request, I’ll show you how I did it. First notice that you’re asking for the projection on any one of the axes of the full figure, which of course is a circle. I choose to project onto the $y$-axis, in other words to ask the range of $y$-values for the points of the circle. Now I make the substitution $z=4-x-y$ into the second equation, and get
$$
x^2 + xy + y^2 - 4x - 4y=-5\,.
$$
Then I just did an implicit differentiation to find where the tangents are horizontal. The result is $\frac{dy}{dx}=-(2x+y-4)\big/(2y+x-4)$, so I want the intersection of the line $y=4-2x$ with the ellipse, which I hope you know has major axis of slope $-1$, minor of slope $1$, not that this is significant. At any rate, when you substitute this $y$ for the $y$ in the equation of the ellipse, you get $3x^2-8x+5=0$, factoring as $(3x-5)(x-1)$. Your point of maximum $y$-value is $(1,2,1)$ and your point of minimum $y$-value is $(5/3,2/3,5/3)$.

Comment: Ok,then it seems my answer is correct.But could you check my reasoning?

Comment: Great Solution.But there is a small typo,instead of $xy$ you should have $dy$ and original $dy$ should be $dx$.

Comment: Thanks, @Roby5, for the alert. The formula as written was $-dy/dx$

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another method to get the answer. By a well known inequality,
$$2(x^2+y^2)\ge (x+y)^2 \iff 2(6-z^2)\ge (4-z)^2 \iff (3z-2)(z-2)\le 0$$

Comment: But this method,sort of assumes that $x$ and $y$ are equal,for equality conditions.

Comment: By sort of,I mean the motivation behind this inequality lies in equality of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Perhaps - in this case sure. However the proof doesn't depend on it, which is what makes it rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with the above proof?

There seems nothing wrong, after all. Effectively, you cross your objects with plane $x-y=0$ and find your point there.

Alternate geometric way is to notice that in point of maximal (minimal) x tangent to the circle has direction $(0, 1, -1)$, so orthogonal circle radius has direction $(2,-1,-1)$; centre of circle is at $(4/3, 4/3, 4/3)$ and radius is $\sqrt{2 \over 3}$. After all this, we get $a = {2 \over 3}, b = 2$ (fixed mistake with initial calculations where sphere *radius* 6 was assumed).

Considering these two ways yield the same result, I don't think it's wrong. Are you sure the statement about your answer being incorrect is flawless?

Comment: $x=y$ holds for maximal/minimal $z$,not for $x$.So $x$ =$z$,might not be true,just as you mentioned.But that doesn't seem to the flaw in my proof.

Comment: @Roby5 Oh, verified again and found that I assumed sphere radius 6. Changed answer, now I think you got it right.